# Does Juniper Networks provide keyloggers with their software?

Tags: security, vpn, privacy-protection

I noticed that I had a "USB Mass Storage Device" plugged in when there wasn't in fact anything plugged in to any USB port. I turned it off via Windows (XP), but it's quite concerning. This was after installing Juniper Networks' software for VPN access to an IT guy's stuff. I also notice there is a service called "dsNcService.exe" which apparently is sending information over the internet (even when I'm not in VPN access). The process restarts itself when I end it. Should I be worried that this software is tracking my keystrokes and broadcasting them to my IT guy?

Comment: Is this your personally owned PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a company use VPN to spy on me?](http://superuser.com/questions/225905/can-a-company-use-vpn-to-spy-on-me)

Comment: @Moab not a duplicate perse, the duplicate given does not refer to this specific case if Juniper Networks provide keyloggers with their software, but to general VPN connections.

Comment: Its related to the same question imo. Paranoid that they installed spy software.

Comment: @Moab I don't agree...

Comment: No kidding?....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dsNcService.exe is a process that is absolutely needed in order to make proper use of Juniper network (and VPN) infrastructure. The reason it is always broadcasting is because it acts as a beacon for the network controller. It is not a key logger per se. The behaviour described here is at least not odd for dsNcService.exe. (It should be in `C:\Program Files\Juniper Networks\Common Files` anyway.)

Of course, your IT guy might've installed masked software to monitor your key strokes anyway. How about just asking your IT department if they do? There probably won't be much you can do about it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a scan for undesirables.

Follow the order given below to properly disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.